# Order of element and group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Give the simplest example of a number $n$ and a number $k$ with $k|n$ and a group $G$ of order $n$ which has no element of order $k$.

I wasn't able to find such a group. Can someone show me an example please?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ has $4$ elements, but no element of order $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $A_4$ there is no element of order 6 but 6/12.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, one can consider groups which are counterexamples for the converse of Lagrange theorem: although $d\mid n$, where $n$ is the order of the group, there is no subgroup of order $d$. The smallest example is the alternating group $G = A_4$, which has $12$ elements but no subgroup of order $6$. For more information see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_%28group_theory%29) under CLT groups.